# How were the CGI scenes created for National Geographic series WW II Greatest Raids

Tags: effects

I've been watching a few of the World War II series on the National Geographic channel lately and they have a series called *WW II Greatest raids*.

In this series they provide CGI reenactments of the battles, sometimes even from a first person perspective, ([examples can be seen here](http://natgeotv.com.au/videos/wwiis-greatest-raids/raid-compromised-81A6E3CA.aspx)). The CGI looks to me almost like a PC video game.

I want to know if they had actually used a PC video game to reenact the battles or was it just purely CGI created in video software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking video games are a form of CGI ([Computer Generated Imagery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-generated_imagery)).
For WW II Greatest Raids National Geographic worked together with [Antimatter Games](http://www.antimattergames.com/projects/wwiis-greatest-raids/) to create the six hours of animation. They used the Red Orchestra 2/Rising Storm game which is based on the [Unreal 3 engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rising_Storm_(video_game)) for creating the graphics.

Advantages of using a game enigne:

- Decent images without much effort

  - Lighting is done by the engine
  - Animations are done by the engine (think about characters walking)
  - Many models are available so you don't have to model many things any more
  - Physics are done by the engine
- Fast cycle time (game engines are designed to perform in real time, so you can check out the final result/render really fast)
- A game engine has a relatively cheap license (some are even free depending on the type of license)

Disadvantages of using a game engine:

- Due to the real time behavior you cannot expect high quality renderings
- Your animations are fixed to what the engine is capable of, think of limitations on the number of characters for example
- Might involve some programming, which you don't want to bother an animator with

Comment: Excellent find! I knew it looked like they used a video game engine :)

Comment: And a relatively old one even...